# 'FloatingArray' object has no attribute 'round'

Tags: pandas

I have no idea why, but when my column in pandas has dtype: Float64, I can't make this command:

```
df['column'].round()
```

Following error follows:

> AttributeError: 'FloatingArray' object has no attribute 'round'

If I set the dtype to : float64, everything goes well. Please, could you explain me why..?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you have to check your version of Pandas or your data?

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'column': pd.array([1.1, 2.2])})
```

```
>>> type(pd.array([1.1, 2.2]))
pandas.core.arrays.floating.FloatingArray

>>> hasattr(pd.array([1.1, 2.2]), 'round')
True

>>> df
   column
0     1.1
1     2.2

>>> df.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 2 entries, 0 to 1
Data columns (total 1 columns):
 #   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype
---  ------  --------------  -----
 0   column  2 non-null      Float64  # <- Float64
dtypes: Float64(1)
memory usage: 146.0 bytes


>>> df['column'].round()
0    1.0
1    2.0
Name: column, dtype: Float64

>>> df['column'].astype(float).round()
0    1.0
1    2.0
Name: column, dtype: float64
```

Github links

- https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/38844
- https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/39751

Minimum Pandas version requirement: 1.3.0